# Rails 3: Stack level too deep when using routes with ":only" or ":as"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm currently upgrading my Rails application from 2 to 3. Everything has been going fine until I finished with the routes.rb file. I'll include the contents below:

```
myApp::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :forum_groups

  resources :forums do
    resources :topics
  end

  resources :topics do
    resources :posts
  end

  match "confirm_user", :to => "users#confirm"

  resources :users do
    resources :comments
  end

  match "moderated_submissions", :to => "submissions#moderated"

  resources :submissions do
    resources :reviews
  end

  match "submissions/:id/download" => "submissions#download", :as => :download_submission
  match "submissions/:id/trash" => "submissions#trash", :as => :trash_submission
  match "submissions/:id/untrash" => "submissions#untrash", :as => :untrash_submission
  match "submissions/:id/moderate" => "submissions#moderate", :as => :moderate_submission
  match "submissions/:id/unmoderate" => "submissions#unmoderate", :as => :unmoderate_submission
  match "submissions/:id/feature" => "submissions#feature", :as => :feature_submission
  match "submissions/:id/unfeature" => "submissions#unfeature", :as => :unfeature_submission

  #Will work on this later. 
  #map.user "users/:username", :controller => "users", action => "show"

  #map.page "page", :controller => "static_page", :action => "show"

  resources :static_pages do
    resources :comments
  end

  resources :categories
  resources :comments, :only => [:destroy]
  resources :reviews, :only => [:destroy]
  resources :features, :as => 'featured'

  resources :announcements do
    resources :comments
  end

  root :to => "pages#root"
  match "browse", :to => "pages#browse"
  match "login", :to => "sessions#new"
  match "logout", :to => "sessions#destroy"
  match "register", :to => "users#new"

  match ":controller/:action/:id(.:format)"
end
```

The problem occurs when any one of these three lines are present:

```
  resources :comments, :only => [:destroy]
  resources :reviews, :only => [:destroy]
  resources :features, :as => 'featured'
```

When any of these lines are present in the routes.rb file I get a, "stack level too deep" error when I try to start the server or the console.

If I remove the statements the application starts fine. If I remove the ":only" and ":as" statements, the application starts fine.

I have tried reordering the routes, and deleting them all except those three and the error still occurs. I have also tried creating a new application from scratch and inserting those three routes. In the case of the new application, it is able to start with those statements.

Any ideas where the problem may lie?

Comment: My first instinct was that something about the fact that comments and reviews are routed to in a nested fashion elsewhere was causing the issue. But the fact that you said you'd removed all the other routes and still encounter the error make me think that it's something on your application's side. Try removing all routes and including only `resources :comments, :only => [:destroy]` and then deleting all the other methods in the `CommentsController` class besides `destroy`, and replacing even that with an empty method body (make yourself a stub view). Then telnet yourself the DELETE request.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried isolated the comments route and removed all methods from the CommentsController except destroy (though I did empty the destroy method). Still nothing. Also, I get the "stack level too deep" error when I try to start up the rails application. I can't even get it to start.

Comment: Turns out it was an old will_paginate plugin. I'm not exactly sure why it caused the error, but after removing the old plugin and replacing it with the updated gem version everything is running fine.

Comment: Crazy as it is, I had the same identical issue and your solution worked fine.